# Where is the information for a particle's spin stored?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin

I understand that spin is an intrinsic property of certain quantum particles, and that it’s just an analogy to classical spin, but that’s not really what I’m asking. Spin is often described as being "information" in quantum mechanics. Information has to be written onto something. Like data bits being written to a hard drive, the magnetic medium is the physical "stuff" that the information is written on. How’s that work for quantum particles? Like with photons, for instance: the photon exists as a wave in both the electric and magnetic fields. The information about a photon’s position and energy (frequency) is "stored" in those fields. Where is the information about it’s spin stored? How about electrons? They are simply an excitation in the electron field. Where is its spin "written"?

Comment: *Spin is often described as being "information" in quantum mechanics.* Do you have a source for this? Are you getting mixed up with *using* spin to store information?

Comment: Nah, spin is not information. It's just that the energy states that depend on the spin are the easiest to use for quantum computations. You just need to apply an external magnetic field, and the spin-up and spin-down states become separated by a precisely controllable amount of energy. And that's what's important for quantum computation experiments: That the transitions between the states are controllable in a robust way.

Answer (score 2):

The information for a particle's spin is stored in the same place that all other information about the particle (e.g. position and momentum) is stored --- in the particle's quantum state.  If you know the state, you know everything there is to know about the probability distribution of outcomes for any measurement whatsoever, including any sort of spin measurement.  This much follows simply from the **definition** of a state as a complete description of everything there is to know about a particle.  The content of quantum mechanics includes the more specific assertion that the state takes its value in some (projectivized) Hilbert space, and evolves over time according to the Schrodinger equation.

If you're worried about using a single Hilbert space to model both (say) position and spin, let $H_1$ be a Hilbert space that is spanned by a basis of position eigenstates, let $H_2$ be a Hilbert space that is spanned by a basis of spin eigenstates, and consider the Hilbert space $H=H_1\otimes H_2$.  A point in (the projectivization of) $H$ contains all the information you could ever reasonably ask for.

Comment: Where is the quantum state stored?

Comment: @sammygerbil:  Perhaps you could clarify the question by telling me what you'd accept as an answer to "Where is the number 3 stored?"

Comment: The number 3 is a mathematical abstraction, just like the quantum state.